# How do I ensure I have unique ids within a loop in a template

Tags: html, django, sqlite

I have the queryset from a formset which is something like this: {[Item 1],[Item 2]}. To display them, I loop through them in the template. But due to the loop, I have a warning that my divs have the same ids. Can anyone suggest what to do? I can just leave it like that if my page purpose is to display the data only. But the page purpose is to view and update the data and correct me if I'm wrong, the div with identical ids will affect the update to the database.

```
                        {{ deviceInterface.management_form }}
                        {% for items in deviceInterface %}
                        
                        <class id= "rowAddition">
                        
                        <div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="{{deviceInterface.moduletype.id_for_label}}">Module Type<span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="text" name="moduletype" required="" id="id_moduletype" class="form-control" value="{{items.moduletype}}">
                                            <!--<select name="moduletype" required="" id="id_moduletype" class="custom-select mb-3">
                                                <option value="">---------</option>
                                              
                                                <option value="TenGigabitEthernet">TenGigabitEthernet</option>
                                              
                                                <option value="FortyGigabitEthernet">FortyGigabitEthernet</option>  
                                                
                                                <option value="GigabitEthernet">GigabitEthernet</option>
                                              
                                                <option value="Ethernet">Ethernet</option> -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="{{deviceInterface.firstportid.id_for_label}}">First Port ID<span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="text" name="firstportid" required="" id="id_firstportid" class="form-control" value="{{items.firstportid}}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="{{deviceInterface.lastportid.id_for_label}}">Last Port ID <span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="text" name="lastportid" required="" id="id_lastportid" class="form-control" value="{{items.lastportid}}">
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="text-sm-center">
                                        <br />
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-rounded"
                                            id="removerow"><i class="dripicons-minus"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        {%endfor%}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of your template that is setting the ids?

Comment: Why not change the id to a class since it is repeated - `class="rowAddition"`? You're not looping over the formset?

Comment: Sorry its deviceInterface, not formset. But without the management line, it still work though. Am i doing something wrong here?  I also changed the div id="rowAdditon" to class="rowAddition". It is not changing anything though.

Comment: You're hard-coded the id of almost all your inputs, you should be using `form.field.id_for_label` instead. Is "di_form" supposed to be a form in the formset that you are iterating over?

Comment: Updated. Sorry for the mistake. Forget change as i copy from my other page. I am using deviceInterface as deviceInterface is getting the queryset from the database. Still not working at the moment. Its cloning same ids but displaying different info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django gives you an iteration counter `{{forloop.counter}}` (or `{{forloop.counter0}}` zero-based) so you can use that to suffix IDs within the loop.

[Django forloop documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Answer (score 0):

I believe in Python with Flask or Django (I do not use Django so not 100% certain) you can add an iterator to the DIV id using the `{{ variable }}` method.  Here's an example from my current pure Python project. While I am using the braced variables for the values of form fields, you can also see one used for an id.

```
{% for val1 in row['content'] %}
    <div class="table width80"><input type="text" disabled size="50" name="newname" id="{{ row['tablename'] }}{{ val1[0] }}" value="{{ val1[1] }}" /></div>

    <div class="table width10"><button type="submit" class="edit" name="update" value="{{ val1[0] }}">Edit</button></div>

    <div class="table width10"><button type="submit" class="delete" name="delete" value="{{ val1[0] }}">Delete</button></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this gives you some useful direction.